# In SWIG compilation : In header file in interface is unable to resolve other header files.

Tags: python, interface, swig

In interface File. I have included a header file.In that Header file there are many header files included but from top tree bases But in Swig is not able to recognize those

Eample:

```
main.h
#include<dir/second.h>
#define PAGE 1
```

Swig is unable to resolve that dir in the header file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
-I<dir>
```

on the SWIG command line to tell SWIG about include paths it doesn't know about.

See [SWIG 2.0 command line documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn2)

Answer (score 4):

SWIG normally does not process #include files recursively.  The reason is you would not want SWIG to process every system header file.  You can override this with `-includeall`, but that is probably not what you want. Instead, consider the following include file:

#### a.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
```

For this, use the following .i file if you want the declarations in a.h, b.h and c.h to be exposed, but do not want the system header files processed:

```
%module example

%{
#include "a.h"
%}

%include "a.h"
%include "b.h"
%include "c.h"
```