# Swig Compilation: Force to select header from specified directory path

Tags: python, c, interface, swig

This is related to inclusion of Header during swig compilation:

The interface file(say foo.i) has some include such as:

%module bindings

%{

#include "foo.h"

%}

The file foo.h is present in the current directory where I am building the swig sources as follows: **swig -perl5 foo.i** ***(Here it picks foo.h from the current directory)***

If I want to include foo.h from some other directory and not the current directory, I try something like this:
**swig -perl5 -I/DIR_PATH foo.i** ***(Here also it picks foo.h from the current directory)***

Even trying this approach, the foo.h is **again selected from the current directory and not from the specified DIR_PATH**. Please suggest a way to ignore foo.h present in the current directory, and force it to select the foo.h in the specified DIR_PATH.

I checked the related post ([In SWIG compilation : In header file in interface is unable to resolve other header files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446143/in-swig-compilation-in-header-file-in-interface-is-unable-to-resolve-other-hea)), but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Anything between %{...%} gets copied verbatim to the SWIG-generated .c files. Hence this is not a SWIG issue, but a compiler issue. Ensure to provide the -I to the compiler command so it can find the included header file:

```
swig -perl5 foo.i
gcc -I /path/to/headers -c bindings.c
```

The first line generates bindings.c, which will contain any code you defined in the %{...%} block in foo.i.

Answer (score 0):

use `#include <foo.h>`.  Most compilers use `""` to search the current directory and then the include path, and `<>` to search only the include path.